# Picasso throws "unresolved reference" for my imageView but it has been declared in the ViewHolder

Tags: android, json, kotlin, picasso

I'm trying to use Picasso to load my RecyclerView with JSON images but the issue is that Picasso does not recognize my `imageView`, despite the fact that it was declared in the ViewHolder.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.list_item.view.*

class PosterAdapter(val movieData: Movies) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){
    val movieList = mutableListOf<Movies>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return movieList.size }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder{

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return PosterHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso
                .get()
                .load("" + R.string.base_URL + "" + movieData.moviePoster)
                .into(PosterHolder.imageView)//identifier imageView is red

        holder.view.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    }
}

class PosterHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    var imageView: ImageView? = null

    fun PosterHolder(view: View){ this.imageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.movie_poster) as ImageView }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {}
}
```

Comment: `holder.view.movie_poster` instead. The notation you're using is for static (companion) objects, whereas you're looking for the member `movie_poster` inside the `holder` object

Comment: @Simon Pardon me but what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: `moviePoster` and `movie_poster` are different.  `moviePoster` is an attribute from my data class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two problem in your code. First problem is you are passing a resource id in url as `R.string.base_URL` .  You should read the resource and pass the value of it not id .
Declare Base url as global.

```
private var BASE_URL: String?=null
```

Get the context in Adapter .

```
BASE_URL=context.resources.getString(R.string.base_URL)
```

Or you can pass `BASE_URL` itself in constructor .

Second problem is you should use `holder.imageView` instead of `PosterHolder.imageView`

```
Picasso
            .get()
            .load(BASE_URL + movieData.moviePoster)
            .into(holder.imageView)
```

Comment: `BASE_URL` is declared in my MainActivity.kt

Comment: Then just pass it to adapter . Do not use only `R.string.base_URL`.

Comment: I have more Kotlin questions.  Would you be fine with chatting further?  I'm having issues with parsing my JSON data.

Comment: I am also a beginner in `kotlin`. I found [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html) very helpful . Other than that  if you stuck somewhere you are always welcome to ask here . You can tag the user in comments to get there attention (i do not know if it works).

Comment: Yea but this site is quite unwelcoming of beginners.  I already got a downvote for asking a legitimate question.

Comment: Thats not completely true . We encourage people to first do some research on the problem, make some effort for there own good . I can not say anything about Down voting. Mostly offT-opic question receives downvotes.

Comment: I've been researching this topic for 3 days, mate.  I've had this experience with stackoverflow before.